# Why do I keep getting the error "The syntax of the command is incorrect"

Tags: windows, command-line, dos

Can someone explain to me why this command reports "The syntax of the command is incorrect."? The first part runs fine by itself, so I know it's not that. And the second part looks to be correct according to `help find`

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\logs>type error.log ^| find /C "2010"
```

I was wondering if it might have to do with line endings in the file, but even something as simple as this gives me the same error:

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\logs>echo "Test1" > test.log

C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\logs>echo "Test2" >> test.log

C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\logs>echo "Test3" >> test.log

C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\logs>type test.log
"Test1"
"Test2"
"Test3"

C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\logs>type test.log ^| find /C "test"
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\logs>type test.log ^| find /C "Test"
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

Comment: I think you might get a better answer to this on SuperUser.com. This question should be migrated there.

Comment: I am not a good batch programmer, but it feels like you don't need ^ symbol before |.

Comment: I'm going to venture a guess and say that your command is syntactically incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to supply the filename to the find command:

find /C "test" test.log

or

type test.log | find /C "test"

Comment: Ah, OK. That works. The example I was basing this off of was using "^|" - how is that different from the pipe character alone?

Comment: FWIW, the additional `^` character works in the following context: `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\logs>dir /B ^| find /N "*.log"` but that command *doesn't* work w/o the `^`

Comment: I believe ^ is a escape character. If you wanted | sign to have no special meaning (piping command executions), you could escape the sign with ^. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#Windows_Command_Prompt

Comment: Ah, I see now. The example I was taking this from actually started out as `for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=[] " %%i in ('dir...` so the `^|` was escaping the `|` only within the context of the `for` command. The final interpretation would be just the pipe. Thanks for leading me to that realization.

Comment: PS: My previous comment was actually incorrect. The `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\logs>dir /B ^| find /N "*.log"` only appeared to work because the pipe was being escaped, so find never actually ran, and the results looked correct because **everything** in that folder is a .log file ^_^